# What is the cast type for System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll()?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

As I go through the `Properties` values in `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll()` and initialize it as a `new-object` to a variable, I noticed after after 50,000 or more my memory starts getting real bad.

To counter this, I am assigning it as a process, but I want to do it in increments of 10,000. To do this, I need to know how to pass the `$list` as an argument, so I need to know it's cast type...
Note: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall(v=vs.110).aspx the type is `A SearchResultCollection object`.

Example code:

```
$domain = "LDAP://some.example.com"
[string[]]$properties = "company" ,"sAMAccountName", "displayName", "name"
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($domain)
$ds = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$ds.Filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'
$ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($properties)
[?]$list = $ds.FindAll()

Powershell -command {
    Param ([string[]]$properties, [?]$list)

    #do stuff with $list
} -args $properties $list
```

what would the `[?]` be in the `[?]$list = $ds.FindAll()` for powershell?

Comment: I would just run `$list = $ds.FindAll()` then `$list.GetType()` and use that. However, since the `SearchResultCollection` object implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`, the type isn't important and you can iterate over the `SearchResult` items in the collection.

Comment: Thanks, the result comes up as `System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection`. Although I'm still getting the error `Program 'powershell.exe' failed to run: The filename or extension is too longAt`. I guess powershell can only handle so much being passed through as an arg when it gets called :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting effected with performance, I recommend creating jobs.

here I am doing it for 1000 objects

it'll go from 0 to 1000

1001 to 2000 and so on .

```
$total = $list.Count
for($($Count=0;$r=0;$t=1000);$Count -lt ($total/1000 -as [int]) ; $($r=$t+1;$T+=1000;$Count++))
{

    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($list)
    #do stuff here
} -ArgumentList $list[$r..$t]

}
```

this will output details of each job,

Do Receive-Job to get the output for each job.

more about_Jobs  here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847783.aspx

best regards,

kvprasoon